# Do Predicates or Actions have any additional properties or qualities which differentiate them to Funcs?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda, functional-programming

A `Predicate` is just a `Func` which returns a boolean:

```
Predicate<T1, T2, T3, ...,Tn> = Func<T1, T2, T3, ...,Tn, bool>
```

And an `Action` is just a `Func` which doesn't return a value:

```
Action<T1, T2, T3, ...,Tn> = Func<T1, T2, T3, ...,Tn, void>
```

**My question:** Do `Predicates` or `Actions` have any additional properties or qualities which differentiate them to `Funcs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. None whatsoever. They are all just delegate types. The only distinction is that some methods take things like `Predicate<T>` (mainly older APIs), and some take the `Func<>` / `Action<>`. One advantage of the `Func<>` / `Action<>` approach is that the signature is obvious from the name (i.e. a `Func<int,float,string>` takes an `int` and a `float`, and returns a `string`), but *that's it*. And even if the delegates have the same *signature*, they are not directly interchangeable (you can't pass a `Func<T,bool>` instance into a method that takes `Predicate<T>`).

Comment: Aside from the fact that `Func<T1,T2,...,TR>` are already in wide use, I wonder what advantages or disadvantages they have versus having a static class `FuncOf<TResult>` with members `NoArgs`,  `WithArg<T>`, `WithArg<T1,T2>`, etc.  The latter style would make clearer which parameter is the return, and could also allow type inference in some cases where argument types could be inferred but the return type could not.

Answer (score 4):

Predicate is just a specialised form of Func for bool return types – ie. it is isomorphic to `Func<X, bool>`.

Action is a totally different beast though. It says "here is a thing that will do something". An Action in other-words will perform side-effects.

Func and Predicate have (potentially at least) the property of [Referential Transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29). They can behave as proper, mathematic functions. This is to say that for an Func a that takes elements of type A and returns a B, it should always return the same B for the same A. This has some rather profound, important and very useful properties – in particular it makes them very easy to test, very easy to reason about and simple to compose.

Actions on the other hand, must perform side effects. Side-effects usually entail ordering concerns, are hard to compose and are a significant source of complexity in programs. Furthermore, they shun the type system, hiding away this complexity behind void.

Action and Func/Predicate are fundamentally very different things.

Comment: No, this is wrong in many ways. Firstly, there is no difference re boxing etc: a `Func<int,bool>` behaves 100% identically (re boxing) to a `Predicate<int>`. Secondly, there is absolutely **not** any guarantee / special behavior of same return from same input. That may be desired, but the expectation is **identical** between the two. For example when using a predicate as a predicate you expect this, too. Equally, side-effects are identical, both in terms of rules and expectations. This is a badly misleading answer, IMO /cc @davenewza

Comment: I do not make the assertion that there is any guarantee of no-side-effects or referential transparency, that is up to the programmer to ensure. All I mention is that they have the potential to be referentially transparent, which is extremely useful. Action on the other hand _must_ perform side-effects, it has no other purpose. Referential-transparent functions are at the core of functional programming – without them you remain in imperative mud.

Answer (score 1):

They're all just delegates. Delegates *can't* declare anything special - they're effectively just method signatures.

You can't add special functionality to a delegate type - at least when declaring one in C#. (It's conceivable that you could in IL, but I've never seen that done.)

Comment: About your last comment: that's interesting, I never considered that. ECMA-335 5th Edition says "While, for the most part, delegates appear to be simply another kind of user-defined class, they are tightly controlled. The implementations of the methods are provided by the VES, not user code. The only additional members that can be defined on delegate types are static or instance methods." I've never seen a delegate type that has additional methods, but it appears to be explicitly permitted.

Comment: @hvd: Maybe I should give that a try :) I wonder whether the C# compiler would allow me to call those methods...

Answer (score 1):

`Action<T>` is not the same as `Func<T, void>`: the former is valid, the latter is not. `void` is not a valid generic type argument.

`Predicate<T>` and `Func<T, bool>` behave exactly the same. However, they are still different types, so you cannot *directly* pass a `Predicate<T>` to a function with a parameter of type `Func<T, bool>`. But as long as you consistently use one or the other, you won't see a difference.